# Is there a way to delete all entries in a section?

Tags: entries, database

I've ended up with loads of duplicate entries after a botched import job.

Is there an easy and safe way to delete all entries in a section, so that I can start over again?

Comment: Are you using the Import plugin by Bob? If so, I believe there is a revert option, otherwise I'd suggest creating a plugin (but that isn't easy, but safe).

Answer (score 7):

If you delete the section, that will delete all the entries in the section as well.

Answer (score 5):

Not really an answer, as such (as others have pointed out there's no way to mass delete from the CP, yet), but when I'm trialling imports I take a DB backup via the CP before and if the import fails or I need to rollback I simply restore the DB.

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no way to select and delete all entries specific to a section through the control panel interface.

Comment: Couldn't you just delete the entry type and re add it?

Comment: Might work. Want to test? But not on a live site:)

Answer (score 2):

@pixelJitsu said "Couldn't you just delete the entry type and re add it?"

@Anna_MediaGirl replied, "Might work. Want to test? But not on a live site:)"

I just tested this on a dev site. Craft asked me if I was sure I wanted to delete the entry type and "all entries that use it".

Poof, they all disappeared from the dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin for that. It can do many things, but most importantly... destroy items :)

https://github.com/am-impact/amcommand